# Strong Version of Leibnitz Rule for Differentiation under the Expectation

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, leibniz-integral-rule

The Leibnitz rule for differentiation under the expectation  provides conditions such on a function $g: \mathbb{R} \times \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} E[g(t,X) ]
\end{align}
where $X$ is a random variable with a distribution $P_X$.

One such sufficient criteria,  which comes from the proof that relies on the dominated convergence theorem, states that
\begin{align}
 | \frac{d}{dt}g(t,x)| \le g(x)
\end{align}
for all $t\in \mathbb{R} $ and almost surely $x$ with respect to $P_X$.

**Question 1:** Can we do better and have weaker conditions?

**Things that I have tried:**

1. Looking at the proof that relies on the dominated convergence theorem it is easy to see that the requirement can be relax to:  $| \frac{d}{dt}g(t,x)| \le g(x)$ for all $x$ and  locally around $t$.  In other words, we don't need to impose a condition for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$.
2. Literature Review:  I found the following `weaker' condition [Theorem~3 here](https://planetmath.org/differentiationundertheintegralsign), which from my understanding requires two conditions:  $g(t,x)$ is absolutely continuous in $t$ for every $x$ and  $\frac{d}{dt}g(t,x)$ is locally integragrable: for every interval $[a,b]$
   \begin{align}
   \int_a^b E \left[ |\frac{d}{dt}g(t,X)| \right] dt
   \end{align}

**Minor Question (Question 2:)**  Do we really need absolute continuity? I think this a difficult property to variety on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: For point 1, yes, you're right; differentiability at a point $t_0$ is a local condition on the function, so we can work point by point, and apply the theorem by restricting the domain of $g:\Bbb{R}\times \mathcal{X}\to\Bbb{C}$ to $g:(t_0-\delta,t_0+\delta)\times \mathcal{X}\to\Bbb{C}$, for a sufficiently small $\delta>0$. For point 2, it seems absolute continuity is necessary, otherwise the statement of the theorem wouldn't even make sense since we may not even be able to define the derivative wrt $t$ almost everywhere. Again, you don't need to verify AC on $\Bbb{R}$, just some open set.

Comment: I'm not sure of weaker hypotheses (thought I wouldn't be surprised if there theorems to this effect)

Comment: Just to confirm absolute continuity needs to hold only locally right? That is, it needs to hold for an arbitrary open set around the point $t_0$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, theorem 3 holds if we write "locally absolutely continuous function of $x$" everywhere in the hypothesis and conclusion.